# $.getJSON in not returning values to respective textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

In my code im using more than one text box to do an event that is if the user enters the code in a text box and onchange event the getJSON should retrieve the code description from the database but i hope there is small problem in my logic so it is not retrieving the code description from database, any one could please help me my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".txtIEcode").each(function(i, el) {
            var $el = $(el),
            $desc = $el.parent().next('td').find(".txtIEdesc");
            $el.on('change', function(){
                alert($desc.val());
                $.getJSON("ieCodedetails.jsp", {codeid: $el.val()},displayResult);

                function displayResult(data) {
                    if (data.error) { // emp not found
                        $desc.val(""); // clear fields
                        alert(data.error);
                    } else { // Found employee. Display details
                        $desc.val(data.name);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode1" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc1" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode2" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc2" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEcode3" class="txtIEcode" style="width:60px;"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtIEdesc3" class="txtIEdesc" style="width:220px;" readonly></td>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your developer tools to see if the request was sent and if a response was received.

Comment: @Lee Taylor what is the network tab in netbeans

Comment: @Pandiramu: In the developer console of your browser, not on the server side.

Comment: @Pandiramu - Most modern browsers have a developer console (Usually accessed by F12). From here you can find all sorts about your HTML/CSS and client-side code. Also, you can see all network traffic to/from your browser. You can use this to determine if your code is firing

Comment: @LeeTaylor im recieving a error like this 
http://localhost:8080/newWRS/ieCodedetails.jsp?codeid=IE2001

Comment: @Bergi  im recieving a error like this localhost:8080/newWRS/ieCodedetails.jsp?codeid=IE2001 –

Comment: @Pandiramu: Um, on *my* localhost there is no error. Please make an [edit] post the server response in your question for us.